# How to draw mobile device edge using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm quite new to CSS and need some help make a mobile edge using CSS.

How can we draw the mobile device edge using CSS? This is what I have tried but unable to do so.

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mobile {
  background: #E0E0E0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E0E0E0, #AEAEAE);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E0E0E0, #AEAEAE);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #E0E0E0, #AEAEAE);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #E0E0E0, #AEAEAE);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E0E0E0, #AEAEAE);
  -webkit-border-radius: 9;
  -moz-border-radius: 9;
  border-radius: 9px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0.5px 0px #fff;
  font-family: Courier New;
  color: #555555;
  width: 20%;
  height: 40%;
  font-size: 41px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border: solid #616161 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #555555;
  margin: 1px;
  outline: #666666 solid 2px
}
.mobile:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile"></div>
```

This is what it should look like :

[image]

How do we do that?

Comment: "mobile edge"? Huh? an edge that moves, or an edge that looks like the side of a cell phone?

Comment: I think he want's to draw a mobile phone and is looking for some CSS that look like the rounded corners of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mobile {
  background: #E0E0E0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E0E0E0, #AEAEAE);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E0E0E0, #AEAEAE);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #E0E0E0, #AEAEAE);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #E0E0E0, #AEAEAE);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E0E0E0, #AEAEAE);
  -webkit-border-radius: 9;
  -moz-border-radius: 9;
  border-radius: 9px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0.5px 0px #fff;
  font-family: Courier New;
  color: #555555;
  font-size: 41px;
  border: solid #616161 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px #555555;
  margin: 1px;
  display: flex;
}
.mobile:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 210px; height: 45px; border: solid #000 1px;" class="mobile">
  <div style="width: 210px; height: 45px; border: solid #fff 1px; " class="mobile">
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 40px;" class="mobile">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would double up on your `box-shadow` declaration instead of trying to wrangle `outline`:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #666666, 0px 2px 2px #555555;
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mobile {
  background: #E0E0E0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E0E0E0, #AEAEAE);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E0E0E0, #AEAEAE);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #E0E0E0, #AEAEAE);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #E0E0E0, #AEAEAE);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E0E0E0, #AEAEAE);
  -webkit-border-radius: 9;
  -moz-border-radius: 9;
  border-radius: 9px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0.5px 0px #fff;
  font-family: Courier New;
  color: #555555;
  width: 20%;
  height: 40%;
  font-size: 41px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border: solid #616161 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #666666, 0px 2px 2px #555555;
  margin: 1px;
}
.mobile:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile"></div>
```

The `0px 0px 0px 1px #666666` syntax gives the shadow zero blur and a 1px offset, essentially replicating a 1px stroke.